# mousedown, touchstart and mouseup,touchend on android

Tags: android, jquery, mousedown, mouseup, touchstart

I have a dynamically made table, when I click some cells and drag to another cell, my function set background to another color. This works without problem on desktop PC, but not on android. Could somebody help ? thanks

```
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row= $('<tr></tr>');

    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        var col= $('<td></td>');

        col.on('mousedown touchstart', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var c= $(this).index();
            var r= $(this).closest('tr').index();
            alert("c"+ " " + "r");

        }).on('mouseup touchend', function (e) {
            var c= $(this).index();
            var r= $(this).closest('tr').index();
            alert("c"+ " " + "r");
        });

        row.append(col);
    }
    table.append(row);
 }
```

problem is when i use my smartphone and select area in table, it always alert position of cell where i started selecting, not a cell where i released finger.

Comment: There are issues with touch events on some android versions, you should check this way..

Comment: thanks for editing, i made mistake when copy+paste code, but this is not my problem